# how to reset security Question in sfdc

Tags: security-token

I changed Reset Security question in setup,Personal,Change my password,even though it is asking for the old question,how can delete old  reset security Question in sfdc.

Comment: Go to your Salesforce record, edit and check generate new password option at bottom, save it. It should generate new password and ask for security question.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to My Settings > Personal > Change My Password. From there, enter your old password, your new password (twice), and you can choose your new security question and answer.

[image: Change Password Screen]

Comment: i did like,but it is showing old reset question.

Comment: @Satya You can click the drop down menu to choose a new question, and type in a new answer.